# variable i is not passed into a function in a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I understand there is no block level scope for var i ; however, in the following code, d.push(); is executed after the initialisation of i, why i here remains undefined?

```
var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     d.push(function(i) {
        console.log('iterator: ' + i);
    });
}
d[0]();//undefined
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: You pushed anounymous function `function(i) { console.log('iterator: ' + i); }` which has a parameter `i`. But when you call the function, `d[0]();`, you didn't pass any argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push an argument-bound version of the anonymous function by using **[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)** thereby ensuring the value of the first argument.

```
var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    d.push((function(i) {
        console.log('iterator: ' + i);
    }).bind(this, i));
}
d[0](); // iterator: 0
d[1](); // iterator: 1
d[2](); // iterator: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
var d = [];

function newFunction(i) {
    var k = i; 
    return function() {
        console.log('iterator: ' + k);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     d.push(
        newFunction(i)
    );
}
d[0]();
d[1]();
```

This works because when you create the new function, it creates a variable scope that doesn't change with your for loop. It saves the state of `i` on each iteration so that when you call them again, it runs with the `i` it was originally declared with.